# Let $(X,Σ,μ)$ be a measure space and $f$ and $g$ are positive integrable functions and $h=f-g$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, functions, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Please please please please please I want some help ,Is there and body here who can help me in this question :

Let $(X,Σ,μ)$ be a measure space and $f$ and $g$ are positive integrable functions and $h=f-g$ , how can I prove that :

$1)$ $h$ is an integrable function

$2)$ $\int hdμ= \int fdμ- \int gdμ$

Comment: Prove this firstly for simple functions (I call simple a function with finite range), and then use an approximation argument for the general case.

Comment: The answer depends on how the integral was introduces. What is the definition of integrable you know?

Comment: Just to make sure: "positive integrable" includes in your definition, that the integral is finite? Otherwise you will run into trouble.

Comment: Hint: Since $f$ and $g$ are integrable over $X$ then each of which can be written in terms of a sequence of simple functions (or characteristic functions). The second part follows directly.

Comment: @mwomath $f$ and $g$ aren't measurable functions

Comment: @Upgrade, the statement that $f,g$ are integrable includes the fact that $f,g$ must be measurable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm presuming that by integrable you mean the integrals of the functions are finite, and by positive you mean that the functions only take positive values.

$h$ will not generally be defined in a strict sense ($\infty -\infty$ is undefined, and depending on which functions $f,g$ you are considering, that could happen), but it will be defined almost everywhere (the functions are integrable, and thus take $\infty$ on a set of  measure $0$), which is all that's needed.

To show this, I'd simply show the more general linearity theorem,

$\int \alpha  f + \beta g dμ= \alpha \int fdμ+ \beta \int gdμ$ for $\alpha ,\beta \in \mathbb R$

1, Show $\int f + g dμ= \int fdμ+ \int gdμ$ is true for simple (here, I mean non-negative) functions.

2, Show the above is true for any $f,g$ that are non negative (Levi).

3, Show that the above is true for any $f,g$ integrable (the respective positive/negative parts of $h=f+g$ are integrable functions, and $h^+ - h^- = f^+ - f^- + g^+ - g^-$ can be re-arranged into $ h^+ +f^- +g^- = h^- + f^+ + g^+$ on which you can use 2 above).

4, show that $\int -fdμ = -\int fdμ$.

Comment: so what is the answer man ?

Comment: The answer is that both 1, and 2, in your original post are true, and I wrote the approach to proving 2, (proving 1, didn't seem worth writing out).